# Subclassing a dataclass with a constructor setting some parameter of the parent class to a default value

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, signature, python-dataclasses

I have a parent dataclass, e.g.

```
@dataclass
class A:
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'
    c = 'c'
```

I want to create a subclass `B` of `A` whose constructor takes elements (b,c,d,e), but automatically sets `a` to 'aa'. The following would work:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b='b', c='c', d='d', e='e'):
        super().__init__(a='aa', b=b, c=c)
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
```

Now, imagine A has a looot of arguments. Is there a way to achieve the same thing as above without a very length call to `super().__init__`? I hope for a solution in which `B` is a dataclass of the form

```
@dataclass
class B(A):
    d = 'd'
    e = 'e'
```

with some additional magic to remove `a` from its signature...

Comment: This link contains exactly what you want to know:
https://itecnote.com/tecnote/python3-dataclass-with-kwargsasterisk/

Comment: Indeed. Using a classmethod does the trick.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!